Require multiple Node versions to conform to one version with Renovate
I have a project which has node defined in three separate places: The Docker image where I am importing my Node base image, in the engines property in the package.json and package-lock.json file and finally in my .nvmrc file. Since the three have different dataSources, they are updated independently and .nvmrc tends to get bumped ahead of the others.
My goal is to get all of the node versions to conform to the version defined in my Dockerfile. If the Dockerfile Node version gets updated by Renovate, the rest should also update. If the Dockerfile Node version does not get updated and there is a new version available to the other files, none of the files update because we are conforming to the latest Dockerfile node version.
I have been hunting around the Renovate docs and other issues, but have not found a great answer.
My first find was the Renovate docs which show that you can group by Node updates, but I don't see anywhere where you can give preference for a specific dataSource, in this case, the version outlined the Dockerfile. The property matchDatasources only tells which dataSource the rule matches to.
What should I do?
